# Server not available on Parse Server Dashboard

Tags: parse-platform

I've setup Parse Server Dashboard on my local machine, and followed the instructions to connect to my Parse Server which is hosted on Heroku.

The Server URL I use to connect to Heroku in my iOS is:

https://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/parse

, so I used this for the Dashboard also.

My config settings are:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "serverURL": "https://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/parse",
      "appId": "appId",
      "masterKey": "masterKey",
      "appName": "appName"
    }
  ]
}
```

, however I am getting the error "Server not reachable. Could not connect to server".

When I remove the https://, I get the error "Server not reachable. Server version too low."

The version is 2.1.4, which is the minimum requirement for the Dashboard.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you navigate in your browser to: http://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/parse ?

Comment: Just started running into this as well, and im on 2.1.6. I opened on issue on github, go check it out. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/994 and https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/130

Comment: @Skelly I get an Application Error page.

Comment: @r2DoesInc the issues are closed?

Comment: @r2DoesInc I see you mention that it was the serverURL that caused the issue. Any tips on how to fix mine? How did you format the URL? Thanks

Comment: The parse dashboard needs a parse server to connect to. You first have to get the parse-server running at http://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/parse .. look at the logs on Heroku

Comment: @Skelly thanks, but my Parse server is definitely working, as I have a live iOS app running from it. It's just a case of the serverURL I believe, as the URL I am using to connect to in in my iOS app isn't working on the Dashboard.

Comment: If you go to your server @ my-app-name.herokuapp.com/parse you should get a json error message, error: "unauthorized". Can you see that page?

Comment: @r2DoesInc yes, I do.

Comment: @r2DoesInc interestingly, with the serverURL: https://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/parse, it seems to pick up the server as I can see my user and installation count, but the server version is too low. I rolled back to 2.1.3 I believe as 2.1.6 was causing my iOS to break. So the serverURL seems to work, I will now go back to 2.1.6 and see what happens, but note that this breaks my iOS app for some reason.

Comment: @r2DoesInc Yes, for some reason, using parse server 2.1.6 breaks my heroku instance.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the config vars (APP_ID, MASTER_KEY, SERVER_URL) between your Parse server and dashboard are set identically. Use https:// instead of http:// for both SERVER_URLs.

To verify your config vars are the same:

1. Go to your Heroku dashboard
2. Open both your Parse Server and Dashboard in new tabs
3. Go to each respective setting tab
4. Click the Reveal Config Vars button under Config Vars and verify that APP_ID, MASTER_KEY, SERVER_URL are identical for both apps.

Answer (score 1):

Try following these two steps:
 `npm install -g parse-dashboard`
Then

```
parse-dashboard --appId yourAppId --masterKey yourMasterKey --serverURL "https://example.com/parse" --appName optionalName
```

The URL should not contain double quotation marks